# F# Mono GTK ConfigureEvent

Tags: f#, mono, resize, gtk, gtk#

Have I used the ConfigureEvent in the right Way ? When I resize or change the position of my window nothing happens, the Label's Text doesn't change to "Changed" as I'm expecting?

```
module Main =
    open System
    open Gtk
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let Main(args) = 
        Application.Init()
        let win = new MainWindow.MyWindow()
//      -----------------------------------------
        let l = new Label( "None" )
        win.Add l
        win.ConfigureEvent.Add( fun _ ->
            l.Text <- "Changed" )
//      -----------------------------------------
        win.ShowAll()
        Application.Run()
        0
```

Comment: does it work with C#? if not, then you're using the wrong API

Answer (score 0):

According to this [faq](http://gtk-sharp.sourceforge.net/faq.html#3.3), you need to add an attribute to the handler for this to work. This C# code works:

```
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
protected void OnConfigureEvent (object sender, ConfigureEventArgs a)
{
    label1.Text = "Changed";
}
```

For this to work in your F# code, you will probably need to have the handler be an instance method instead of a lambda, so you have something to attach the attribute to. I'm guessing you should really be using some other event, though I'm not sure which.